# Get the id of a newly inserted row php

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am trying to get the insert id from a newly inserted row. I use the following method to query. However I am unable to get the inserted id.

```
function query($sql) {
    global $link;
        $debug = false;

    //get the sql query
    $args = func_get_args();
    $sql = array_shift($args);

    //secure the input
    for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
        $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
        $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
    }

    //build the final query
    $sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

    if ($debug) print $sql;

    //execute and fetch the results
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        $id = $result->insert_id; //no result, what do I put here?

    if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

        $rows = array();

        if ($result!==true)
        while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             array_push($rows,$d);
        }
        //return json
        return array('result'=>$rows, 'id'=>$id);

    } else {

        //error
        return array('error'=>'Database error');
    }
}
```

How can I modify this method to get the insert id?

Comment: Why use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` when mysqli supports prepared statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

This value would be called the "identity", keep that in mind when searching for information pertaining to this.

Answer (score 0):

check the below links

mysql_insert_id()

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html